# 32-bit executable file on 64-bit ubuntu could not be installed

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am trying to install Hume functional programming language compiler on Ubuntu 64 bit and the errors i am getting is this

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I am a noobie in ubuntu so please can you explain to me in a simple language because all the resources i found is too difficult to understand.

Comment: Did you install from a package or from source?

Comment: I download it from the Hume website http://www-fp.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/hume/downloads/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable 32-bit binary compatibility on Linux Mint 11 x64](http://superuser.com/questions/307064/how-to-enable-32-bit-binary-compatibility-on-linux-mint-11-x64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is very simple.

The binary you are downloading has been compiled on a 32-bit system and thus requires 32-bit libraries.  You can probably try installing:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

and see if this will resolve it but it is unlikely.  You should try to see if the Ubuntu Repositories have Hume interpreter tested for this distribution save that you may have to install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) likely with RedHat to make this work.